# iOS Private Relay option breaking an API?

Tags: .net, flutter, azure, api, azure-api-apps

The iOS release version 15 has come with a new option "Private Relay". When this setting is ON the API are not working.

Here is the setting in the iCloud

[image: Private Relay]

This is giving a socket exception

> flutter: SocketException: Connection failed, address = {url}.com, port = 80

Comment: What is your question?  What does "not working" mean?  Do they throw an exception or error?  Does your app crash?  What steps have you taken to debug this?  There is no information in your post that we could use to help you.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/prepare-your-network-for-icloud-private-relay/

Comment: why are you getting a "flutter" exception in a Xamarin app?

Comment: @Jason sorry my bad it's a flutter app, not a Xamarin App. APIs are in .Net core